# Foreman-Installer failed to install - puppet cert --generate FQDN returned 23 instead of one of [0] - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ssl, puppet, foreman, installation

I tried to install Foreman serveral times at my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. Foreman 1.5 and 1.6 always fail at the same time with following error :

```
/usr/bin/puppet cert --generate ubuntutest.domain.com returned 23 instead of one    of [0]
/Stage[main]/Puppet::Server::Config/Exec[puppet_server_config-generate_ca_cert]    /returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/bin/puppet cert --generate ubuntutest.domain.com returned 23 instead of one of [0]
/Stage[main]/Puppet::Server::Config/Exec[puppet_server_config-generate_ca_cert]:   Failed to call refresh: /usr/bin/puppet cert --generate ubuntutest.domain.com returned 23 instead of one of [0]
/Stage[main]/Puppet::Server::Config/Exec[puppet_server_config-generate_ca_cert]:  /usr/bin/puppet cert --generate ubuntutest.domain.com returned 23 instead of one of [0]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Failed to call refresh: Could not start   Service[httpd]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1:
/Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Could not start Service[httpd]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1:
Installing             Done                                               [100%] [...............................................................................]
Something went wrong! Check the log for ERROR-level output
```

After i generate a certificate by hand. apache startet successfully and die foreman web-interface is reachable.

I followed the foreman docu und tried: `puppet agent --test` following happenend:

```
Info: Caching certificate_revocation_list for ca
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to find ubuntutest.infraserv.com via exec:    Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb ubuntutest.infraserv.com' returned 1:
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed when  searching for node ubuntutest.infraserv.com: Failed to find ubuntutest.infraserv.com    via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb  ubuntutest.infraserv.com' returned 1:
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

.... :(

Comment: Do you have any logs in your apache error file ?

Comment: No, only in syslog: `Sep 23 09:27:32 ubuntutest libapache2-mod-passenger: apache2_invoke: Enable module passenger
Sep 23 09:27:32 ubuntutest libapache2-mod-passenger: apache2_reload: Your configuration is broken. Not restarting Apache 2` So it seems thier is more than one problem ?

Comment: If i try to start apache: `The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/05-foreman-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ubuntutest.domain.com.pem' does not exist or is empty
Action 'configtest' failed.`

Comment: OK, cert is absent. You should try to generate your certificate "by hand"

Comment: ok i generatet a certificate by hand. following the puppet docu: [link]https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html#step-1-clear-and-regenerate-certs-on-your-puppet-master apache startet successfull. Hopefully all other parts work. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

For a Foreman-only host that is not a Puppetmaster, clear your Puppet's entire SSL directory on your Foreman host and fully regenerate your certificates.

Also ensure that your /etc/hosts file has a properly-formatted record for your host. Older Foreman installs used to complain about this, and it won't hurt. I'm definitely a fan of infinite lease lengths and a fixed reservation for Foreman if you need to use DHCP in your environment.

> 10.0.0.2 foreman1.production.example.com foreman1

Once this is done, this particular error should be resolved.